# TypeORM: How to use sub queries in queryBuilder

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have the following PostgresSQL:

```sql
SELECT symbol, created_at
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) symbol, created_at
  FROM update_history
  WHERE exchange = 'TEST' AND data_type = 'ANY'
  ORDER BY symbol, created_at DESC
) h
ORDER BY created_at ASC
LIMIT 500;
```

I'm trying to write this out using TypeORM's `queryBuilder`, but can't seem to work out how it translates to the above.

The closest I've got right now (which isn't correct, and doesn't return the correct data set) is the following:

```js
const result = this.repository
  .createQueryBuilder('history')
  .select(['history.symbol', 'history.createdAt'])
  .where('history.exchange = :exchange', { exchange: 'TEST' })
  .addFrom(
    (subQuery) =>
      subQuery
        .select(['h.symbol', 'h.createdAt'])
        .distinctOn(['h.symbol'])
        .from(HistoryRecord, 'h')
        .where('h.exchange = :exchange', { exchange: 'TEST' })
        .andWhere('h.dataType = :dataType', { dataType: 'ANY' })
        .orderBy({ 'h.symbol': 'DESC', 'h.createdAt': 'DESC' }),
      'h',
    )
  .orderBy({ 'history.createdAt': 'ASC' })
  .take(500);
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using `this.repository` at all as it'll add unnecessary additional `from` on `history` table. Also, you need to take care of the aliasing here. The alias `h` specified as the second argument of the `addFrom` method should be different from the one specified inside subquery `from`. To fix all these issues, you can do something like this:

```
const connection = getConnection();
const result = connection.createQueryBuilder()
  .select(['history.symbol', 'history.createdAt'])
  .addFrom(
    (qb) => {
      return qb.select(['h.symbol as symbol', 'h.createdAt as createdAt'])
        .distinctOn(['h.symbol'])
        .from(HistoryRecord, 'h')
        .where('h.exchange = :exchange', { exchange: 'TEST' })
        .andWhere('h.dataType = :dataType', { dataType: 'ANY' })
        .orderBy('h.symbol', 'DESC')
        .addOrderBy('h.createdAt', 'DESC')
      },
    'history'
  )
  .orderBy('history.createdAt', 'ASC')
  .take(500);
```

And it will generate exactly the query you want. If you don't want to use the connection object, you can simply use manager instead:

```
const result = getManager().createQueryBuilder()
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working with .getManyRaw()! I'm trying to use .getMany() but I'm getting the following: "Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias 'history'". 

Ideally I'd like to use an .innerJoinAndSelect() with this too. Any ideas?

Comment: Since `getConnection()` is deprecated, you can achieve the same with `this.repository.manager.connection.createQueryBuilder()`